# Visualization results of dbscan using ELKI

Tags: java, elki

I am using ELKI's implementation of DBSCAN to cluster.

Could you tell me how can I visualize this data?

```
 DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(data);
 Database db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);
 db.initialize();
 SquaredEuclideanDistanceFunction dist = SquaredEuclideanDistanceFunction.STATIC;
 DBSCAN<NumberVector> dbscan = new DBSCAN<>(dist,0.000008,10);
 de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.data.Clustering<Model> result = dbscan.run(db);
```

Comment: There is no data in this question, so how could we know what visualization is adequate?
Also how do you expect the result to appear - in a file, in a new window? Then either use the `ResultVisualizer` or the `ExportVisualizations` class.